# How to calculate average mark for each student

Tags: postgresql, select, union, average

I have a table `"Register"`

with columns:

```
  class_id bigint NOT NULL,
  disciple text,
  datelesson date NOT NULL,
  student_id integer NOT NULL,
  note character varying(2)
```

now I want to calculate the average score for each student_id and the number of absent

```
Select * from "Register" as m

Join

(SELECT AVG(average), COUNT(abs) FROM (SELECT
  CASE
      WHEN "note" ~ '[0-9]' THEN CAST("note" AS decimal) 
  END AS average,
  CASE
      WHEN "note" ='a' THEN "note"
  END AS abs
FROM "Register" ) AS average)n 
on class_id=0001 
And datelesson between '01.01.2012' And  '06.06.2012' 
And discipline='music' order by student_id
```

Result is this:

```
0001;"music";"2012-05-02";101;"6";7.6666666666666667;1
0001;"music";"2012-05-03";101;"a";7.6666666666666667;1
0001;"music";"2012-05-01";101;"10";7.6666666666666667;1
0001;"music";"2012-05-02";102;"7";7.6666666666666667;1
0001;"music";"2012-05-03";102;"";7.6666666666666667;1
0001;"music";"2012-05-01";102;"";7.6666666666666667;1
```

The result I receive is for the whole column but how do I calculate average marks for each student?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could look like this:

```
SELECT student_id
     , AVG(CASE WHEN note ~ '^[0-9]*$' THEN note::numeric
                                       ELSE NULL END) AS average
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN note = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS absent
FROM   "Register"
WHERE  class_id = 1 
AND    datelesson BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND  '2012-06-06' 
AND    discipline = 'music'
GROUP  BY student_id
ORDER  BY student_id;
```

I added a couple of improvements.

- You don't need to double-quote lower case identifiers.
- If you want to make sure, there are *only* digits in `note`, your regular expression must be something like `note ~ '^[0-9]*$'`. What you have only checks if there is *any* digit in the string.
- It's best to use the ISO format for dates, which works the same with any locale: `YYYY-MM-DD`.
- The `count` for absence works, because `NULL` values do not count. Ypu could also use `sum` for that.
- As class_id is a number type, `bigint` to be precise, leading zeros are just noise.
  Use `class_id = 1` instead of `class_id = 0001`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like you are missing a "group by" clause. I am not familiar with postgress but I suspect the idea applies just the same.

here is an example in transact-sql:

```
--create table  register
--(
--class_id bigint NOT NULL,
--  disciple text,
--  datelesson date NOT NULL,
--  student_id integer NOT NULL,
--  grade_report integer not null,
--  )


--drop table register

delete from register
go

insert into register 
    values( 1, 'math', '1/1/2011', 1, 1)
insert into register 
    values( 1, 'reading', '1/1/2011', 1, 2)
insert into register 
    values( 1, 'writing', '1/1/2011', 1, 5)

insert into register 
    values( 1, 'math', '1/1/2011', 2, 8)
insert into register 
    values( 1, 'reading', '1/1/2011', 2, 9)

SELECT student_id, AVG(grade_report) as 'Average',  COUNT(*) as 'NumClasses'
from register
WHERE  class_id=1
group by student_id
order by student_id
```

cheers

Comment: `go` is not a valid PostgreSQL statement. Additionally Postgres requires a `;` to terminate a statement.